# C# integer what is the output of this?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a bit confused with this C# snippet. Can someone explain what does the following does?

```
 int i = 5;

 i = i + 6;
```

Comment: Why? What don't you understand?

Comment: What are you finding confusing? And why didn't you just compile it to check?

Comment: Homework? If so, tag appropriately.

Comment: the console app just closes without doing anything?

Comment: You need to pause for input after you print the result, `Console.ReadKey(true);`, or you could set a breakpoint.

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine(i); Console.ReadLine();` to see the output

Comment: Press F10 (step by step debugging) to debug it. Hit F10 each time Visual Studio should go to the next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creates an integer variable with the value of 5 named i, then adds 6 to it, resulting in:

```
11
```

Answer (score 11):

```
int i = 5; // sets the variable i to the value of 5. (i = 5)
i = i + 6; // sets the variable i equal to itself plus 6. (i = 5 + 6)
```

Thus i = 11 *(5 + 6)*

Answer (score 5):

```
int i = 5;
```

Creates a variable called `i` which stores integers, and gives it the initial value `5`.

```
i = i + 6;
```

Modifies `i` to be the value of `i + 6`. Confusion here is avoided by remembering the rule that everything on the right hand side of the assignment operator `=` is evaluated before the assignment takes place. Thus, the previous value of `i`, namely `5`, is used. So when run, the code becomes

```
i = 5 + 6;
```

And so therefore `i` has the value `11`.

Comment: I note that everything on *both sides* of the operator is evaluated before the assignment takes place, not just everything on the right side. First the left side is evaluated, then the right side is evaluated, and then the assignment takes place.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int i = 5;
```

Creates an integer i and sets its value to 5.

```
i = i + 6;
```

Sets the value of i to be i + 6 (11 in this case)

Answer (score 2):

`=` means **assign** and not **equals**

```
int i = 5; // Means "put 5 in variable i"
i = i + 6; // Means "get the value in i, add 6 to it and put the result back in i"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the skinny, line by line.

```
int i = 5;
```

Assigned a primitive integer variable called "i" with the value 5.

```
i = i + 6;
```

The code in this line evaluates what is on the right side of the = first, getting the value before attempting to assign it. Therefore, i + 6 becomed 5 + 6 which is 11. Then, the primitive variable "i" is assigned the newly calculated value 11. So, i = 11;

Hope that helps!